# Setting up a small network with a redundant WAN setup

Tags: networking, switch, wide-area-network, redundancy

Asked on the network stack but referred here, partly because lower grade equipment.

Small office and we are trying to piece together a network with our two wans (diff ISPs) a switch and a few routers, the goal is to have redundant connectivity. Below is a diagram with a rough idea of what we are looking to do.

The wan side consists of an ADSL router for one ISP and a cable modem and vanilla router for the other ISP.  The switch is a TP-LINK that has port trunking and VLANSs (with tagging and link aggregation groups). The other side of the switch at this time are a network printer, two wired pcs and a wireless router.

I’m told this should be possible but this is really my first dive into VLANs, trunking, etc so not quite sure how to fit the pieces together correctly.

Here is the diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally got hold of TP-Link and they advise what I am looking to do with this model switch is not possible and they have recommended an alternative.

Comment: Is the switch a Layer 3 switch, though?  If so, this may be possible and they might just be trying to upsell you.